# In the original edition of Prince of Persia, what happens when you die?

Tags: prince-of-persia

I just finished the PlayStation version, and I am curious about how much harsher the original was.

Do you go to the beginning of the level, or does the game end and you go back to level 1?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

In the original Prince of Persia you start at the very beginning of a level after dying. You can do this an unlimited number of times.

However, there is a time limit on a complete playthrough of the game, so if you restart a level too many times you will not have enough time to finish the complete game. This made the game quite hard, as with no indication of how much time is needed to complete the remaining levels, dying too often in the beginning would mean having to restart the entire game in order to be able to complete it.

Comment: another curiosity: what happens when the timer runs out? In the playstation version, you are allowed to continue playing and exploring latter levels

Comment: @josinalvo from the DOS version I remember a cut scene indicating you failed and the highscore screen came up. But this was 20 years ago, my memory might be a bit rusty.

Comment: @josinalvo Jafar kills the princess and the game ends.

Comment: In a way this is fair enough. If you are on a real mission you don't know if you're too late or still have more time, generally speaking.

Comment: When the timer runs out https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NRqKvBtRvTg. I'd have sworn there was an animation of the princess dying but this would suggest not.

Comment: Timer was 60 mins except for SNES version [120 mins], btw - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prince_of_Persia_(1989_video_game)#Plot

Comment: sidenote: back then, I remember calling him Prince of Persil, due to the amount of times his bloody clothes would come out brilliant white again once you restarted the level. That game was an all time classic

Comment: @CJ when you are on a real mission, you don't restart if you die though ;)